# Не отображается Html элемент

Tags: html, веб-программирование, asp.net

Имеется текст, который хранится в БД, он содержит в себе ссылку. Почему браузер её не отображает? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div id="publicationContent">
    <div id="publicationName">
        @Model.Tittle
    </div>
    <div id="publicationText">
        @Model.Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Air вы же видите, что не делает. Это скрин страницы

Comment: Вы обрабатываете чем-то строку?

Comment: @slo_nik нет, просто текст в блок выводится

Comment: @Air в каком смысле? ссылка есть, текст тоже

Comment: покажи код............

Comment: Не понятно почему и зачем, ты хочешь извещать браузер том, о чем он по умолчанию должен, может и увидит???  Я уже раза три свои коменнты убрал и изменил...  В конец запутал...  Ты объясни нормально, что ты хочешь сделать...

Comment: при записи в базу текст обрабатывается?

Comment: @Air я хочу, чтобы у меня в тексте ссылка была. Но бразуер она не воспринимается

Comment: как на скрине что бы было

Comment: @Air скрин показывает, что код html не читается, а выводится как текст

Comment: @slo_nik просто текст записывается в виде строки

Comment: это понятно. Вы не используете никаких функций для обработки текста перед записью в базу?

Comment: @slo_nik нет, текст никак не обрабатываю

Comment: ну если бы он не обрабатывался, то выводился бы нормально, так как Вам надо. А здесь, скорей всего, где-то идёт обработка текста. Информации очень мало предоставили. Так можно гадать долго, но если выводить при помощи htmlspecialchars_decode(), то должна ссылка отображаться нормально.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-otobrazit-tegi-na-veb-stranitse

Comment: @Air не понимаете, у меня обратная ситуация, пишутся теги вместо вставки ссылки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="publicationContent">
    <div id="publicationName">
        @Model.Tittle
    </div>
    <div id="publicationText">
        @Html.Raw(Model.Text)
    </div>
</div>
```